# Apply jQuery to search result webparts sometimes fails

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, search-results

On the start page of a Sharepoint 2013 Intranet portal I put a search result webpart. The webpart is styled and formatted into a slider with jQuery & CSS

For some reason sometimes the jQuery on search result webparts is not triggered. This only occurs after an iisreset or when there's a delay for some other reason. After refreshing the page the slider loads without any problem.

I've tried several solution (_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames, SP.SOD.execeuteFunc, executeOrDalayUntilScriptLoaded), but none of them seems to work. My current code looks like:

```
function PageLoadTrigger() {
   // initiate slider
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("PageLoadTrigger");
```

It only seems to happen on search result webparts. All other jQyery runs fine.

Is anyone aware of this problem and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it is a js script file that is not running but I had a same sort of problem with sp.js file (SP.ClientContext was not working). Solved it with this:

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "sp.js", function () {
        //rest of my code
    });

});
```

replace the first argument of getScript for the URL of your script file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. I only added the no conflict option.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function () {

    jRoot = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    j.getScript(jRoot + "/_layouts/15/SP.js", function () {
        PageLoadTrigger();
    });
});
```